# Linux sendmsg returning EBADF with a good file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, network-programming

I've got a snippet of server code here that runs fine on my machine, but fails with an EBADF on my Amazon EC2 instance. I understand that Amazon Linux images are heavily modified, but I think it is more likely that the error is on my part. I'm trying to pass a socket from a parent to a child instance using UNIX sockets.

Here is the code then I'll talk about what I've tried after. This code the main server loop to listen for connections, accept them, and pass the socket to another process.

main.h

```c
#define COUNT(array) sizeof array / sizeof array[0]
int id;
int server;
struct worker {
    int pid;
    int to;
};
struct worker *workers;
struct task {
    unsigned int client;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t length;
};
```

main.c

```c
void mainLoop() {
    INFO("Waiting for connections");
    struct task newTask;

    while(1) {
        if (++id >= NUM_WORKERS) {
            id = 0;
        }

        newTask.client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr *)&newTask.addr, &newTask.length);
        if (newTask.client < 0) {
            INFO("Accept failed with result %d and error (%d) '%s'", newTask.client, errno, strerror(errno));
            continue;
        }

        char buf[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof newTask.client)];
        struct iovec iov[] = {
            {&newTask, sizeof newTask}
        };
        struct msghdr msg = {
            NULL, 0,
            iov, COUNT(iov),
            buf, sizeof buf,
            0
        };

        struct cmsghdr *cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
        cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
        cmsg->cmsg_type = SCM_RIGHTS;
        cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof newTask.client);
        *CMSG_DATA(cmsg) = newTask.client;
        msg.msg_controllen = cmsg->cmsg_len;

        int result = sendmsg(workers[id].to, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT);
        if (result < 0) // result = -1 on my server
            INFO("sendmsg failed with %d: (%d) '%s'", result, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

The worker[id].to sockets were made using socketpair, like so:

```c
int sockets[2];
socketpair(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockets);
```

The INFO macro is my own to either fprintf to an informational log or stdout depending on if debug is defined, and appends a newline at the end.

If I remove the control message section and set buf to NULL (in other words, don't pass a socket) then the message is sent just fine. In addition, when I call fnctl with F_GETFL to get the status of all of the sockets involved (server, worker[id].to, and newTask.client) they all return a status of 2 (O_RDWR). And again, it works on my machine, but not on the Amazon server.

Does this code look erroneous or does Amazon have a bug? What else could I try or how else could I debug this?

The server is running CentOS 7 on an Amazon EC2 instance. The kernel version is 4.19. My local machine is Debian Sid with the same kernel.

Comment: Surprising it works at all. Are you sure? File descriptors are local to the creating process, unless inherited, which these aren't. You can't just pass them around like that to other processes.

Comment: The cmsg(3) man page describes how to do it and gives an example: https://linux.die.net/man/3/cmsg From my understanding, this is how a server could run on protected ports without root permissions before capabilities were introduced. An elevated process would create the socket for them. The kernel reads the control buffer section and copies the required data to the new process.

Comment: @Tyler There is an example in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html The first thing I'd look to is the alignment (see where they use a union). If all else fails consider picking up that example and seeing if it works (both on your machine and on the remote one).